# Quotient of an abelian surface by an antisymplectic involution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

What can we say about the quotient of an abelian surface by an antisymplectic involution?

Comment: I would conjecture that it is always $CP^1 \times T^2$, because I see no other examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Denote by $\sigma$ the involution on the abelian surface $A$ and set $X:=A/\sigma$. The eigenvalues of the action of $\sigma$ on $H^0(\Omega^1_A)$ are $+1$ and $-1$.
So $\sigma$ has no isolated fixed points and it follows that $X$ is smooth with $h^1(\mathcal O_X)=1$.
There are two possibilities:

1) $\sigma$ has no fixed point. Then the quotient map $A\to X$ is \'etale and $X$ is a bielliptic surface almost by definition.

2) $\sigma$ has a fixed point. Then, up to a translation,  we may assume that $\Sigma$ is an endomorphism. The fixed locus is a union of elliptic curves and $X$ is ruled. This can be seen either by classification of surfaces or observing that $A$ contains a family of translates of elliptic curves on which $\sigma$ acts as multiplcation by $-1$.

Comment: In case 1), if $X=E_1 \times E_2/ G$, how can we relate $A$ with $E_1 \times E_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Averaging a Kaehler class over the involution, and taking
the corresponding Ricci-flat metric, we may assume that
the involution preserves a flat metric on a torus. 
At each fixed point, the eigenvalues of the involution
are +1, -1, and the fixed point set is a subtorus $T_0\subset T$.
This means that the involution acts as -1 on $T_1 :=T/T_0$,
hence the quotient is a product $T_0\times T_1/\{\pm 1\}$,
that is, $T_0 \times {\Bbb C} P^1$.

Comment: What about the map $T \times T \to T \times T$ that switches the two factors? One can't always write the original torus as a product of the subtorus and the quotient torus. However you can do this up to $2$-torsion so $Sym^2(T)$ is the only counterexample.

Comment: the map which switches two factors is symplectic, and we need antisymplectic

Comment: @Misha: the map that switches factors is antisymplectic, since $dx\wedge dy$ goes to $dy\wedge dx$.